# Xml in Asp.net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

What I am trying to do is load an xml file into my mvc application but regardless of how I implement it, it always returns a count of zero, I know the way im doing isnt exactly the best by storing the xml loader in the configuration class which is made by the migrations method but it was working and now it has stopped  quoting "only part of the address can be reached" I was wondering if there was a way of fixing this?

Catalog.cs

```
public class CatalogController : BaseController
{    
    // GET: Catalog
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        List<Category> Categories = DbContext.Categories.OrderBy(c => c.Name).ToList();
        int NumberofBooks = DbContext.Books.Count();
        List<PublicationThumbnail> bookItems = GetBookThumbNails(5);

        HomeViewModel homeViewModel = new HomeViewModel(Categories, NumberofBooks, bookItems);
        return View(homeViewModel);
    }

    public ActionResult Search(string c = null, string t = null)
    {
        string searchMessage = (t == null ? "Publications" : t);
        if (c != null)
        {
            searchMessage += " in " + c;
        }
        List<PublicationThumbnail> imageThumbNail =
            FilterPublications(c, t).Select(p => new PublicationThumbnail(p)).ToList();
        SearchViewModel searchViewModel = new SearchViewModel()
        {
            FilterMessage = searchMessage,
            Thumbnails = imageThumbNail,
            ResultsCount = imageThumbNail.Count
        };
        return View(searchViewModel);
    }

    public ActionResult View(int id)
    {
        Publication foundPublications = DbContext.Publications.Find(id);
        if (foundPublications != null)
        {
            Account currentUser = null;
            if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                currentUser = AccountManager.GetCurrentUser(User);
            }
            return View(new PublicationViewModel(foundPublications, currentUser));
        }
        return HttpNotFound();
    }

    [Authorize]
    public ActionResult Download(int id)
    {
        Account account = AccountManager.GetCurrentUser(User);
        if (account != null && (account.Subscribed() || account.PurchasedItem(id)))
        {
            Publication publication = DbContext.Publications.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Id == id);
            return View(publication);
        }
        return HttpNotFound();
    }

    private List<Publication> FilterPublications(string category, string publicationType)
    {
        List<Publication> results = new List<Publication>();
        if (publicationType != null)
        {
            if (publicationType.ToLower() == "books")
            {
                results.AddRange(DbContext.Books);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            results.AddRange(DbContext.Publications);
        }

        if (category != null)
        {
            Category categoryMatch = DbContext.Categories.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Name == category);
            if (categoryMatch != null)
            {
                results = results.Where(p => p.Categories.Contains(categoryMatch)).ToList();
            }
        }
        return results;
    }

    private List<PublicationThumbnail> GetBookThumbNails(int count)
    {   
        List<Book> books = DbContext.Books.Take(Math.Min(count, DbContext.Books.Count())).ToList();
        return books.Select(j => new PublicationThumbnail(j)).ToList();
    }
}
```

Books.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Books>
    <Book>
        <Title>The Rabbit Who Wants to Fall Asleep: A New Way of Getting Children to Sleep</Title>
        <Description>The groundbreaking No. 1 bestseller is sure to turn nightly bedtime battles into a loving and special end-of-day ritual. This child-tested, parent-approved story uses an innovative technique that brings a calm end to any child's day.</Description>
        <Authors>Carl-Johan Forssén Ehrlin</Authors>
        <Chapters>4</Chapters>
        <Edition>1</Edition>
        <PublicationDate>2016-05-21T10:50:23.5602265-04:00</PublicationDate>
        <PublicationFormat>PDF</PublicationFormat>
        <FileLocation>App_Data/Publications</FileLocation>
        <ISBN>978-3-319-30715-2</ISBN>
        <Categories>
            <Category>
                <Name>Other</Name>
            </Category>
        </Categories>
        <ThumbnailLocation>TheRabbit.jpg</ThumbnailLocation>
        <Price>4.00</Price>
    </Book>
</Books>
```

Configuration class

```
internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<HullUniversityPress.DataAccessLayer.HullPressContext>
{
    public Configuration()
    {
        AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;
    }

    protected override void Seed(HullPressContext context)
    {
        if (context.Books.Count() == 0)
        {
            SeedPublicationCategories(context);
            SeedBooks(context);
            SeedAccounts(context);
            SeedSubscriptions(context);
        }
    }

    private XDocument LoadXmlDoc(string fileName)
    {
        XDocument xmlDoc = XDocument.Load("HullUniversityPress/App_Data/" + fileName);
        return xmlDoc;
    }

    private void SeedBooks(HullPressContext context)
    {
        XDocument xmlDoc = LoadXmlDoc("Books.xml");
        foreach (XElement j in xmlDoc.Root.Elements("Book"))
        {
            Book newBook = new Book()
            {
                Title = j.Element("Title").Value,
                Description = j.Element("Description").Value,
                ISBN = j.Element("ISBN").Value,
                FileLocation = j.Element("FileLocation").Value,
                ThumbnailLocation = j.Element("ThumbnailLocation").Value,
                Chapters = int.Parse(j.Element("Chapters").Value),
                Edition = int.Parse(j.Element("Edition").Value),
                Langauge = (Language)Enum.Parse(typeof(Language), j.Element("Language").Value),
                Authors = j.Element("Authors").Value,
                Price = decimal.Parse(j.Element("Price").Value),
                PublicationFormat = (PublicationFormat)Enum.Parse(typeof(PublicationFormat), j.Element("PublicationFormat").Value),
                PublicationDate = DateTime.Parse(j.Element("PublicationDate").Value)
            };
            ParseCategories(newBook, context, j.Element("Categories"));
            context.Books.Add(newBook);
        }
    }

    private void ParseCategories(Publication publication, HullPressContext context, XElement categoryRoot)
    {
        publication.Categories = new List<Category>();
        foreach (XElement category in categoryRoot.Elements("Category"))
        {
            string categoryName = category.Element("Name").Value;
            Category match = context.Categories.Local.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Name == categoryName);
            if (match != null)
            {
                publication.Categories.Add(match);
                match.Publications.Add(publication);
            }
            else throw new Exception("Unidentified category: " + category.Element("Name").Value + ", Categories: " + context.Categories.Local.Count());
        }
    }

    private void SeedPublicationCategories(HullPressContext context)
    {
        context.Categories.AddOrUpdate(
            new Category("Other")
            );
    }

    private void SeedAccounts(HullPressContext context)
    {
        context.Accounts.AddOrUpdate(
            new Account("Customer@Customer.com", "Hello12345")
            );
    }

    private void SeedSubscriptions(HullPressContext context)
    {
        Account account = context.Accounts.Local.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Email == "Customer@Customer.com");
        Book bookSub = context.Books.Local.FirstOrDefault();
        if (account != null && bookSub != null)
        {
            context.Purchases.Add(new Purchase()
            {
                Account = account,
                Publication = bookSub,
                Format = PublicationFormat.PDF
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Any sort of help / pointed in the right direct would be greatly received.

Comment: Most of this code has nothing to do with your question - [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: You add items to the context but you don't seem to call .SaveChanges()

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how that code ever worked,I've re-created the problem on my side and changed this line:

```
XDocument xmlDoc = XDocument.Load("HullUniversityPress/App_Data/" + fileName);
```

to this:

```
XDocument xmlDoc = XDocument.Load(Server.MapPath("~/HullUniversityPress/App_Data/" + fileName));
```

Now the `XDocument` is being loaded with the content of Books.xml:

[image]